# android beam large file

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

**I want** to use Android Beam (large file) for beaming an object to another device. I save the object as Java file and then let it beam. The beam works fine and the file is send to the receiving device.

**The Problem** is so far I wasn’t able to open it on the receiver device. I can only open it if I use as mimetype text/plan but than any other app with an intent filter for text/plan is be able to open it.

**My Question is**, is there are way to use custom mimetype? Or is there another way to make sure only my Application is able to open the received file?

MyIntent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: How is the code that you're using to send the file?